# Lavavel js script

Tags: laravel

I`m using laravel blade with js script.

Blade:

```
<link href="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" defer rel="stylesheet">
```

script.js:

```
console.log('test');
```

When I start server, console is clear. I can see in network, that script is downloaded, but nothing happend. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<link rel="stylesheet">` is for embedding CSS, not JS.

You want to use `<script>` instead:

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" defer></script>
```